# MySQL return different count from select rows, missing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently did the following query in MySQL:

```
select received, 
       verified, 
       accession, 
       qualityControl, 
       testMnemonic, 
       preliminaryReview, 
       sangerComplete
from Accessions order by accession;
```

It was missing data, so I looked for a specific row

```
select received, 
       verified, 
       accession, 
       qualityControl, 
       testMnemonic, 
       preliminaryReview,
       sangerComplete 
from Accessions where accession='14259115189';
```

The second query return the correct single row for that accession. I went back to the general query, but 14259115189 is not showing up at all. Incidentally, I followed up with a `select count(*) from Accessions` and it returned a different number of rows from the general query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most tools for performance purposes they will only display few records...what tool are you using?

Comment: Is it only displaying 0-1000? If there are more records then it may only show you some part of the whole query.

Comment: you sure the UI did not display something like ..... as the last row?

Comment: Where are you running the query?  MySQL Workbench for example limits results to the first 1000 records.

Comment: maybe try removing each of the columns one at at time to isolate if there is a problem with one of them?

Comment: The last row is normal. It stops at 746. The count(*) is 1508

Comment: This is being run in a terminal with normal MySQL